# Google Oauth2.0 authentication in a console application

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use Google shopping API. In order to use the API,  my application should be authenticated using OAuth2.0. Looks like this method involves user interaction (where user allows the application to access the resource)
Is it possible to do OAuth authorization in non web applications with no user interaction?

Comment: How would you envision this working? How would the application know the user to authorize as, and how would the service know you have a user's authorization? What specifically are you trying to do? This might be a case for a Service Account.

Comment: @Jason- Thanks for your response. I am trying to code a executable which uploads product data to google commerce search using Google shopping APIs. In order to use this, I need to authorize and get access token using OAuth. All the implementations, I have seen as user interaction. I am wondering how can I implement the whole process as normal executable.

Comment: @testuser did you achieve the use of Google API in C# without Web context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a good case for using a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount). This would mean that your application isn't running as a *user* but *as itself*. That is, as a made up account corresponding to your APIs Console project.

Various official client libraries support the Service Account flow as described in the link above, but C# is not listed among them, so you may have to write it yourself. (Though [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=203) claims it's supported in the google-api-dotnet-client library, I couldn't find the source for this feature after a minute or two of looking).